# Laravel access inverse relation information

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to access some information of a parent object using Elequent but having a hard time figuring out how it works. Lets say a Beer belongs to a Brewery and a Brewery has many beers. I have the beers controller, model and view using the a brewery_id to connect the two. I can access the relationship by a brewery page listing the beers so I know the are pairing, but how do I have a beers page with all the beers and the brewery they belong to? Basically reversing how I get the relationship.

Brewery Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Brewery extends Model
{

    public function Beers(){

        return $this->hasMany(Beer::class);

    }
}
```

Beers Model

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Beer extends Model
{

    protected $table = "Beers";

    public function Breweries() {

        return $this->belongsTo(Brewery::class);

    }
}
```

Beers Controller

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Beer;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

class BeersController extends Controller
{

    public function index() {

        $beers = Beer::all();

        return view('beers.index', compact('beers'));
    }

    public function show(Beer $beer) {

        return $beer;

    }

}
```

Beers View

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <h1>Beers</h1>

            @foreach ($beers as $beer)

                <div>
                    {{ $beer->name }}
                    {{ $beer->brewery->name }}
                </div>

            @endforeach

        </div>
    </div>

@stop
```

Comment: {{ $beer->brewery->name }} change it to {{ $beer->Breweries->name }} because your relation method name is Breweries or rename your method to brewery in Beer model. use small letter for methods

Comment: @umefarooq That worked and thanks for the heads up on lower casing methods. If you post this as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{{ $beer->brewery->name }} change it to {{ $beer->Breweries->name }}
```

because your relation method name is Breweries or rename your method to brewery in Beer model. use small letter for methods

Answer (score 0):

I guess this will fix your probleme

**Controller**

```
class BeersController extends Controller
    {

    public function index() {

        $beers = Beer::with('Breweries')->get();

        return view('beers.index', compact('beers'));
    }
```

**View:**

```
@section('content')

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <h1>Beers</h1>

            @foreach ($beers as $beer)

                <div>
                    {{ $beer->name }}
                    {{ $beer->Breweries->name }}
                </div>

            @endforeach

        </div>
    </div>

@stop
```